# Azure Stream Analytics: how to achieve high-availability?

Tags: azure, high-availability, azure-stream-analytics

I'm evaluating Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) for a mission critical event data processing application.  The SLA for ASA is 99.9, which is not sufficient for my use case.  Has anyone developed a good strategy for ensuring high availability with ASA?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2015/06/16/achieving-geo-redundancy-with-asa/? Just out of curiosity, what are you using for input and output, what are their respective SLA's?

Comment: @PeterBon, Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  That specific documentation evaded my search efforts.  My input is a geo-redundant pair of event hubs, and the output is a geo-redundant pair of service bus queues, so everything is HA with the exception of ASA... until I implement the architecture in the documentation that you referenced.